# Don't repeat combinations from math.random()

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, combinations

How can I make this code don't repeat combinations and after finishing combinations, I should alert that it's finished.

And second question, is there any way to reset combination (reset randomise)?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
        .content{

        margin-top:100px;
        margin-left:16%;
        float:left;
        }
        #about{
        padding:20%;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        #btn{
        padding-right:125px;
        text-align:center;
        }
        .number{
        float:left;

        }
        .color{
        margin-top:-20px;
        float:left;
        }
        p{
        width:50px;
        height:34px;
        line-height:23px;
        text-align:center;

        }
        .nmb1{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;


        }
</style>
<div class="number">
<div class="nmb1">1</div>
<div class="nmb1">2</div>
<div class="nmb1">3</div>
<div class="nmb1">4</div>
<div class="nmb1">5</div>
<div class="nmb1">6</div>
<div class="nmb1">7</div>
<div class="nmb1">8</div>
<div class="nmb1">9</div>
<div class="nmb1">10</div>
<div class="nmb1">11</div>
<div class="nmb1">12</div>
<div class="nmb1">13</div>
<div class="nmb1">14</div>
<div class="nmb1">15</div>
<div class="nmb1">16</div>
<div class="nmb1">17</div>
<div class="nmb1">18</div>
<div class="nmb1">19</div>
<div class="nmb1">20</div>
</div>
<div class="color">
<p id="changeText"></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

</div>
<div class="content">
<button id="about">Variant #<a id="clicks">0</a></button><br/>
<button id="btn"onClick="onClick()">NEXT</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var textarea = ['N', 'Y'];
        var colors=['red','green'];
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('p').each(function(){
        var randomC = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
        $(this).css('background',colors[randomC]);
        $(this).html(textarea[randomC]);
        });
        });
        });

        var clicks=0;

        function onClick(){
        clicks+=1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
        };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add all of your div ids in an array. Then random a number between 0 and the array length. Then you can do your code on that div and remove its entry from the array

Comment: What do you mean by "Repeat combinations"? Do you want the Y/N order to be different every time, or just different from the previous time?

Comment: Y/N should be different every time while I click reset button

Comment: Then it's only random for the first click. After that it would just toggle the value Y or N...

Answer (score 0):

Per your desired behavior mentioned above, take a look at this snippet. It will randomize the first set, and then simply toggle them so they are never the same as they were in the previous set from then on out.

```js
var textarea = ['N', 'Y'];
var colors = ['red', 'green'];
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#btn').one('click', function() {
    $('p').each(function() {
      var randomC = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      $(this).css('background', colors[randomC]);
      $(this).html(textarea[randomC]);
    });
    $('#btn').click(function(e) {
      $('p').each(function() {
        var isY = $(this).html() == textarea[0];
        $(this).css('background', isY ? colors[1] : colors[0]);
        $(this).html(isY ? textarea[1] : textarea[0]);
      });
    });
  });

});

var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 16%;
  float: left;
}
#about {
  padding: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#btn {
  padding-right: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}
.number {
  float: left;
}
.color {
  margin-top: -20px;
  float: left;
}
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nmb1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="number">
  <div class="nmb1">1</div>
  <div class="nmb1">2</div>
  <div class="nmb1">3</div>
  <div class="nmb1">4</div>
  <div class="nmb1">5</div>
  <div class="nmb1">6</div>
  <div class="nmb1">7</div>
  <div class="nmb1">8</div>
  <div class="nmb1">9</div>
  <div class="nmb1">10</div>
  <div class="nmb1">11</div>
  <div class="nmb1">12</div>
  <div class="nmb1">13</div>
  <div class="nmb1">14</div>
  <div class="nmb1">15</div>
  <div class="nmb1">16</div>
  <div class="nmb1">17</div>
  <div class="nmb1">18</div>
  <div class="nmb1">19</div>
  <div class="nmb1">20</div>
</div>
<div class="color">
  <p id="changeText"></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>

</div>
<div class="content">
  <button id="about">Variant #<a id="clicks">0</a>
  </button>
  <br/>
  <button id="btn" onClick="onClick()">NEXT</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```